# How to build fat jar for EE CDI?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, cdi

Those days everybody talks about microservices and containerless deployments using fat-jars, and framework like Dropwizard or Springboot support you with that. With all the EE components available as separate implementations it should be possible to assemble your own jar of the required componentes (i.e. Weld, Jersey, Jetty).

When using Java EE based CDI, there is this concept of *BDA* (Bean Deplyoment Archive), that defines a set of CDI-enabled Beans bundled in jar, together with a `beans.xml` containing some additional information for the BDA, like interceptors.

How do I combine those BDAs into a single uber-jar without loosing the information of the `beans.xml`? The maven `jar-with-dependencies` just copies all files into one, overriding the previous file (or keeping the first one, don't know exactly).

Is the concept of a fat-jar compatible with EE CDI at all? Won't some CDI semantics get lost when being all merged into one BDA, i.e. scope of Alternatives.

Comment: Perhaps [wildfly swarm](http://wildfly-swarm.io/) will do that for you - just an idea hoping it might help, as I haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip from the weld guys http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/#5

Basically,make sure you aggregate your extensions and include a valid `beans.xml`

Comment: and what about combining multiple BDAs?

Comment: @GeraldMücke not sure what you mean.. maybe clarify.  The whole point here is that you have one archive, not many.

Comment: I have a maven project with multiple modules containing beans (and beans.xml with interceptors, stereotypes etc) which are the BDAs. And I have an "assembly" module, that should create a fat jar including the BDAs and the "infrastructure" (Weld, etc)